# Задача на рекурсию про лесенку из кубиков

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Эта тема не вопрос, а работающее решение данной задачи в рекурсивном виде и оно ищет максимальную высоту лесенки, ничего больше.
Как заметили в комментариях можно решить эту задачу через арифметическую прогрессию.
Лесенкой называется набор кубиков, в котором каждый верхний слой содержит кубиков меньше, чем в предыдущем. Требуется написать программу вычисляющую число лесенок из N кубиков.
Очень долго искал в интернете какой-то адекватно работающий вариант и все же решил сделать сам и помочь кому-то со схожей проблемой. Публикую решение ниже.
Для тех, кто хочет разобраться. Сначала самым первым слоем является только один кубик, в последующих итерациях создаётся слой длины больший на 1, чем предыдущий. И так до тех пор, пока не достигается результат.

```
int layersCount = 1;

int Stairs(int n, int previousLayer)
{

    int thisLayer=0;
    while (thisLayer - previousLayer !=1 && n - (thisLayer + previousLayer)>0)
        thisLayer++;

    if (thisLayer - previousLayer == 1) layersCount += 1;
    if (n - thisLayer-previousLayer > 0)
        return Stairs(n - previousLayer, thisLayer);
    else
        return layersCount;

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << Stairs(n,1);
}
```

Comment: Вы задачу толком не сформулировали. О каком "решении" идет речь?

Answer (score 3):

Округленное вниз положительное решение квадратного уравнения:

```
(k + 1) * k / 2 = n

k = floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * n)) / 2)
```

*(Привет от маленького Гаусса.)*

Comment: может решение из вопроса перенести в ответ?

Comment: @michael_best Мне не нравится решение из вопроса. Я против циклов и рекурсий там, где ответ просто считается.

Comment: Это лабораторная и передо мной была задача решить рекурсивно и просто найти максимальную высоту лесенки, а не все её вариации.

Comment: @ВладимирСырых Тогда точно сформулируйте, что именно вы сделали "для будущих поколений" - со всеми ограничениями.

Comment: @ВладимирСырых "When the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

Comment: @Harry подкорректировал и указал, устраивает?

Comment: я начал решать задачку через арифметическую прогрессии и, оформляя ответ, понял что это и есть ваше решение. Вы хоть пояснили бы.

Comment: @ВладимирСырых Описание - устраивает, решение - нет... Оно из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно"? Я сначала решил, что вы считаете количество способов сложить ступеньки из N кубиков - там действительно рекурсия могла пригодиться (вкупе с мемоизацией), но для вашей задачи Igor совершенно прав. Понимаете, ну не будете же вы выкладывать решение задачи о перемножении двух целых чисел в виде суммирования в цикле?

Comment: Вот когда кому-то понадобится решение данной задачи, этот человек придет в этот тред и увидит кучу полезной информации и про рекурсию, и про арифметическую прогрессию, и про решение в виде одного уравнения. Это же круто :)

Comment: уравнение исходит и прогрессии. Комментарии со временем удаляются.

Comment: @ВладимирСырых Если человек будет не писать такое сам, а искать готовое - сомневаюсь, что он сумеет найти... :)

Answer (score 2):

Задачи "ищет максимальную высоту лесенки" и "число лесенок из N кубиков" - разные.

Отвечу на вторую, т.к. про неё написано "требуется найти", и приведена более-менее чёткая формулировка:

> Лесенкой называется набор кубиков, в котором каждый верхний слой
>   содержит кубиков меньше, чем в предыдущем. Требуется написать
>   программу, вычисляющую число лесенок из N кубиков.

Это число разбиений (partitions) N на различные слагаемые  `(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22..)`

```
import functools
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)   #простейшая мемоизация
def growparts(n, last):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    result = 0
    for i in range(last + 1, n + 1):
        result += growparts(n - i, i)
    return result

for k in range(15):
    print(k, growparts(k, 0))
```

Comment: А это на каком языке программирования?

Comment: Это Python, но кроме необязательных functools, всё остальное не специфично  (`int growparts(int n, int last) { if (n==0) return 1 `...)